# MVVM dependency on javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, design-patterns, mvvm

I am familiar with MVC but not MVVM. I checked various posts related to difference between MVC/MVVM/MVP.

Even I checked Microsoft's office link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463786.aspx but each time I found a common thing among these links is that, they explained implementation of MVVM using third party JavaScript libraries (Angular, knocknout, Ember etc).

**Does it means that MVVM is dependent on these type of libraries ?**
**Is it possible to implement MVVM using simple jquery?**
Please clarify about this concept.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MVVM` is a design pattern. `Angular`, `Knockout`, `Ember` etc are all specific implementations of the pattern. If you choose to use their particular implementation, you will be dependent on their libraries.

Comment: It means all these libraries are released to work collaboratively, after MVVM's introduction ?

Comment: No. MVVM is not a standalone thing - it is a way/method of writing code. The same as MVC (even tho' Microsoft have released an MVC framework called MVC) and MVP.

Comment: thanks @toadflakz, is it possible to write code in MVVM like pattern using simple jquery, without any library ?

Comment: Your code would just need to reflect the requirements of the pattern to qualify - if you can separate the layers like that using jquery and no other libraries, then the answer is yes.